# Forest line breaking with folder style: Anchor to first line

Tags: line-breaking, forest

Is there a way with the `forest` package to anchor the edge to the first line of a multi-line node?

[image]

In this example, I would like to have the middle horizontal edge point to the **123** of the multiline text node.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}% geometry or similar is needed for correct A4 layout
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    folder,
    grow'=0,
    align=left
  },
  [ Top level
  [ \textbf{ABC} ]
  [ \textbf{123} Also some longer text.\\Also some longer text.  Also some longer text.  Also some longer text.  Also some longer text.\\Also some longer text.  Also some longer text.  Also some longer text.  Also some longer text.\\Also some longer text.  Also some longer text.]
  [ \textbf{ZYX} ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done, although the solution is a bit hacky.

First of all, I added `base=top`. Behind the hoods, `align=center` creates a tabular environment and `base=top` sets the `t` vertical alignment. This gets us to the base of the first line.

To draw the edge, I set the `edge path` manually. I took the definition from the `folder` style (in `forest-lib-edges.sty`) and adapted the second coordinate to `([yshift=.6ex].base west)` --- so base west and shifted up a bit (adjust `.6ex` to your taste).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}% geometry or similar is needed for correct A4 layout
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    folder,
    grow'=0,
    align=left,
  },
  [ Top level
  [ \textbf{ABC} ]
  [ \textbf{123} Also some longer text.\\Also some longer text.  Also some longer text.  Also some longer text.  Also some longer text.\\Also some longer text.  Also some longer text.  Also some longer text.  Also some longer text.\\Also some longer text.  Also some longer text.,
    edge path'/.expanded={
      ([xshift=\forestregister{folder indent}]!u.parent anchor) |- ([yshift=.6ex].base west)
    },
    base=top,
  ]
  [ \textbf{ZYX} ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly for me, I put it into a custom style in my `\forestset` as `long description/.style={edge path'..., base=top}`. Maybe this could be added to the package as a default style?

Comment: This might be a bit too specific to be the default. But I'm thinking of a better way to define `folder` (see e.g. my recent answers to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/567434/16819) and to deal with (forest's) anchors in general (like the ability to shift them).