# forest - Obtaining a special directory tree like formatting

Tags: forest

Here is a code found in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511769/forest-labeling-levels-in-a-horizontal-tree).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}                      
forked edges,                       % Tree style 
for tree={grow=0, s sep=0pt, 
edge= thick,  
anchor=base west,  
font=\strut\footnotesize\sffamily},
                                    %
[,phantom                           % Paranormal root  (BOO!)
                                    %  
[aaaa                               % Real branch   
    [bbb,tier=b, 
        [eeeeeeeeeeee, tier=c 
            [fff, tier=d]]] 
    [ccc 
        [gg, tier=c] 
        [hhh, tier=c]] 
    [ddddddddd 
        [iii, tier=c]]]                          
                                    %
[One,for tree={color=gray,no edge}  % Ethereal branch 
[Two, tier=b                            
[Three,  tier=c                       
[Four, tier=d]]]]                   
                                    %  
]                                   % Closing poltergeist
                                    %
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

I would like to adapt the code above to obtain what I have added by hand in red. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `calign=child, calign child=-1`. Child number -1 is the last child.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}                      
forked edges,                       % Tree style 
for tree={grow=0, s sep=0pt, 
edge= thick,  
anchor=base west,  
font=\strut\footnotesize\sffamily},
                                    %
[,phantom                           % Paranormal root  (BOO!)
                                    %  
[aaaa, calign=child, calign child=-1                               % Real branch   
    [bbb,tier=b, 
        [eeeeeeeeeeee, tier=c 
            [fff, tier=d]]] 
    [ccc, calign=child, calign child=-1 
        [gg, tier=c] 
        [hhh, tier=c]] 
    [ddddddddd 
        [iii, tier=c]]]                          
                                    %
[One,for tree={color=gray,no edge}  % Ethereal branch 
[Two, tier=b                            
[Three,  tier=c                       
[Four, tier=d]]]]                   
                                    %  
]                                   % Closing poltergeist
                                    %
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

You can also place the `calign` options in the `for tree`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}                      
forked edges,                       % Tree style 
for tree={grow=0, s sep=0pt, 
edge= thick,  
anchor=base west,  
font=\strut\footnotesize\sffamily,
calign=child, calign child=-1},
                                    %
[,phantom                           % Paranormal root  (BOO!)
                                    %  
[aaaa                               % Real branch   
    [bbb,tier=b, 
        [eeeeeeeeeeee, tier=c 
            [fff, tier=d]]] 
    [ccc 
        [gg, tier=c] 
        [hhh, tier=c]] 
    [ddddddddd 
        [iii, tier=c]]]                          
                                    %
[One,for tree={color=gray,no edge}  % Ethereal branch 
[Two, tier=b                            
[Three,  tier=c                       
[Four, tier=d]]]]                   
                                    %  
]                                   % Closing poltergeist
                                    %
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```